# A picturebox import issue C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

Import option not working on picturebox in C#.

[image]

The import button was not generate the browse option.

How to write **in project folder?** (how to short path?)

```
private void home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e))'
{
    /*pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:/..../documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/Janani/Janani/Properties/Energy.png";
    //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    pictureBox1.Size = new Size(400, 200);

    pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "C:/..../documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/Janani/Janani/Properties/HandHolding.png";
    //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(200, 200);
    pictureBox2.Size = new Size(400, 200);*/

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:/Users/Warrior/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/Janani/Janani/Properties/Energy.png");
    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:/Users/Warrior/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/Janani/Janani/Properties/HandHolding.png");
}
```

In code, first one was not working. Second one ok!

Comment: "first one was not working. Second one ok!" -- sounds like the first file does not exist, or maybe `pictureBox1` isn't what you think it is. Only you can find out which, because only you can see what's on your disk and what's in your project.

Comment: all the files are in!

Comment: hi buddy see the image, why I can't to use import button and other image set buttons in visual studio? I have reinstalled this app several times about this problem. Problem still here. I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From VS menu bar you can select **Project -> Project properties(on the bottom)** and then go to **Resources** tab. From here, you can add the resource(s) from disk, by hand. Then you can access them from code like this:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Image = Properties.Resources.NameOfResource;
```

Don't forget to set the rest of PictureBox properties like Size, Location and so on ...